# Illegal string offset Warning in a php page

Tags: php, html

I am currently editing a document named "test.php" and want to upload a csv file, read the data in it, and output some information on this page.

I have this html code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table width="600">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<tr>
<td width="20%">Select CSV file</td>
<td width="80%"><input type="file" name="filename" id="file" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="20%">Select Model file</td>
<td width="80%"><input type="file" name="dontworry" id="file" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Submit</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have this php command:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    // get value from csv file
    $csv = array();
    $file = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
    {
    $csv[] = $result;
    }

    fclose($file);
    
    // set non repeat value by a list 
    $onedarray = array_2d_to_1d($csv);
    $onedarraynoneempty = array_merge(array_unique(array_filter($onedarray, "myFilter")));
    $arraynum = array_merge(removeNum($onedarraynoneempty));
    $counts = array_count_values($onedarray);
    
    // get assiciation and print out the associate result

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arraynum)-1; $i++){
        /*
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arraynum[$i]);
        echo '</pre>';
        */
        $newlist = array_merge(removeActual($arraynum, $i));
/*
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($newlist);
        echo '</pre>';
*/

        count_support($csv, $arraynum, $arraynum[$i], $counts[$arraynum[$i]], $newlist);
    
        }

    

/*
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arraynum);
    print_r($arraynum[2]);
    echo '</pre>';
*/
    
}

// finding connection between the other product and $item in one line, if it has 3 line connection, output the message
function count_support($arr, $count, $item, $totalcount, $newlist){
    for ($b = 0; $b < count($newlist); $b++){
    $finalcount = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
      for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr[$i]); $j++) {
        if ($newlist[$b] != null){
        $compare = $newlist[$b];
        
        if($arr[$i][$j][$item] != null && $arr[$i][$j][$compare] != null){
            $finalcount ++;
            }
        }
      }
    }
    
    //output each result in the support and confidence
    $confidence = 3 / $totalcount;
        if($finalcount = 3)
        {
            $part = $newlist[$b];
            echo $item . " -> " . $part . "Support: 3, Confidence: " . $confidence . "<br/ >"; 
        }
    }
}

// change 2d array into 1d array
function array_2d_to_1d($input_array) {
    $output_array = array();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($input_array); $i++) {
      for ($j = 0; $j < count($input_array[$i]); $j++) {
        $output_array[] = $input_array[$i][$j];
      }
    }

    return $output_array;
}
// ignore null element in the array
function myFilter($var){
    return ($var !== NULL && $var !== FALSE && $var !== "");
}
// remove number index in 1d array
function removeNum($var){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($var[$i])) {
        unset($var[$i]);
    }
    }
    return $var;
}
// remove on element in an array
function removeActual($var, $listnum){
    unset($var[$listnum]);
    return $var;
}
?>
```

[Here is my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHnJJ.png), I want to save the entire csv file element into an 2d array, and traverse the entire array, output the support connection between two products equal to 3 on the page. The approximate effect is as follows:

```
blueberry -> pear, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.75
pear -> blueberry, Support: 3, Confidence: 1
blueberry -> tang celery, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.75
tang celery -> blueberry, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.75
lotus root -> tomato red, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.6
tomato red -> lotus root, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.75
pear -> tang celery, Support: 3, Confidence: 1
tang celery -> pear, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.75
coriander -> spinach, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.6
orange -> spinach, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.6
persimmon -> spinach, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.6
luzon mango -> persimmon, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.75
persimmon -> luzon mango, Support: 3, Confidence: 0.6
```

But when I finally pressed submit, many lines jumped out:

```
( ! ) Warning: Illegal string offset 'Tomato Red' in C:\wamp64\www\test.php on line 84
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0037  411368  {main}( )   ...\test.php:0
2   0.0059  470080  count_support( )    ...\test.php:60

( ! ) Warning: Illegal string offset 'Lemon Yellow' in C:\wamp64\www\test.php on line 84
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0037  411368  {main}( )   ...\test.php:0
2   0.0059  470080  count_support( )    ...\test.php:60
```

This error grew indefinitely and eventually crashed the website.
Here is my line 84 in function **count_support**:

```
if($arr[$i][$j][$item] != null && $arr[$i][$j][$compare] != null){
```

I want to know how to improve my php code to make this error disappear.

Comment: The warning message should include the file name and line number that caused the problem. Please post the complete messages

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I made some changes and wrote the file name and line number that caused the problem at the bottom of the question.

Comment: The error message means that you have a string value, but you are trying to use associative array access syntax on it. Make a debug output of `$arr` using `var_dump`, to see what it actually contains at that point.

Comment: I used this function if(in_array($item, $before) && in_array($compare, $before)) to replace my previous error page, and the error no longer occurred.